# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: . xls(The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java

I was trying to read the data from the excel file, but the console is giving the exception that system can not find the specified path. But i have given the right path, file is also accessible.Please help me out with this.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("someurl");

Workbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("E:\\TestDataforSelenium1.xls"));
Sheet sh= book.getSheet("TestData");
for(int i=0; i<sh.getRows(); i++)
{
    String username=sh.getCell(0, i).getContents();
    String password=sh.getCell(1, i).getContents();
    driver.findElement(ByName.name("uid")).sendKeys(username);          
    driver.findElement(ByName.name("password")).sendKeys(password);         
    driver.findElement(ByName.name("btnLogin")).click();
    try
    {
        Alert alt=driver.switchTo().alert();        
        String alerttext=alt.getText(); 
        System.out.println(alerttext);
        if(alerttext.equalsIgnoreCase("User or Password is not valid"))
        {
            alt.accept();
            System.out.println("test case pass with invalid credential and valid error message");   
        }
        else        
            System.out.println("test case pass with invalid credential");   
        }           
    catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex)      
    {       
        String url ="http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php";    
        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php"))  
            System.out.println("Verify that user is successfully able to login.");
        else    
        System.out.println("Verify that user is not able to log into the application.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please verify your excel extension, are you sure it isn't xlsx, the new format?

Comment: `But i have given the right path` obviously not. Also check that you don't have something like `E:\\TestDataforSelenium1.xls.xls`, because there are still some people out there, who let windows hide the file ending.

Comment: No there is no issue with the extension, it is .xls  and as per i can understand the path is correct.